# mongodb - Count all documents for a date

Tags: mongodb

I have documents in a collection with date format

`updated: 2022-10-25T05:04:47.904+00:00`

How to modify the query to get the count for today's date

```
const today = new Date()
....
await db.collection('posts').countDocuments({"updated": today})
```

Answer (score 2):

### With MongoDB v5.0+,

Use `$dateTrunc` with `unit: "day"` to perform date-only comparison.(i.e. without time part). You can use built-in `$$NOW` variable to get today's date.

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      {
        $dateTrunc: {
          date: "$updated",
          unit: "day"
        }
      },
      {
        $dateTrunc: {
          date: "$$NOW",
          unit: "day"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j3zVL0Sk-VE)

---

### With MongoDB v4.0+,

you can rely on comparing 2 integer division result of `updated` and `$$NOW` to get today's record.

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      {
        $toInt: {
          $divide: [
            {
              $toLong: "$updated"
            },
            86400000
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        $toInt: {
          $divide: [
            {
              $toLong: "$$NOW"
            },
            86400000
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/R7NJd14Jr4C)

Comment: Getting error `MongoServerError: Unrecognized expression '$dateTrunc'`  - `codeName: 'InvalidPipelineOperator',` I posted an answer below that works but I think there might be a more straight forward way.

Comment: @Kal what is your MongoDB version? [$dateTrunc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateTrunc/) is new in MongoDB v5.0+. Updated the answer to include another alternative for older MongoDB version

Answer (score 0):

This works but not sure if its the best way. Seems complicated for a simple task to match date.

So set hours to 0000 and then check for documents greater than that. So everyday, new Date() will be today and this will only show documents from today.

```
const today = new Date();
today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
const query = { "updated": { $gte: today } };
..
await db.collection('posts').countDocuments(query)
```

Comment: You may need to take extra care on timezone issues if you are not in UTC timezone

Comment: @ray This is for an admin panel and will only be used in the same timezone for analytics purposes. Makes sense though.